# Как в Laravel узнать, приходило ли оповещение от определённого пользователя?

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно написать код, который не будет допускать повторного оповещения от одного и того же пользователя по одному же посту. Для этого я писал следующий код:

```
$is_challenged_before = 
        $defender 
        ->notifications()
        ->where('initiator_id', $initiator_id)
        ->exists()
        &&
        $defender
        ->notifications()
        ->where('post_id', $post_id)
        ->exists() ? true : false;
```

И это не работает, и я, кажется знаю почему. Дело в том, что столбцы post_id и initiator_id в БД находятся внутри json-столбца data. Поэтому, laravel не видит эти столбцы. Я хотел узнать, предусмотрена ли такая ситуация ларавелем или нет? Нужно искать какие-то обходные пути или у ларавел есть для этого специальные функции? Если есть, то буду благодарен если вы мне укажите на них). Спасибо))

Comment: Для этого надо сделать определение уведомлений в БД в соответствии с вашими требованиями и подвязать вашу модель [через morphable](https://medium.com/@alouinimedamin/customize-your-database-notification-and-database-channel-in-laravel-576c8fa5f498) в таблицу уведомлений, так как иначе данные будут в ней в виде сериализованного массива JSON.

Comment: Спасибо большое, статья была очень полезной